# PYSPARK UDF to explode records based on date range

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a Noob in Python & Pyspark.
I need to explode a row of patient into yearly dates, such that each patient has 1 row per year.

I wrote a python function (below), and registered it as pyspark UDF (having read many articles here). My problem is that when I apply it on my pyspark dataframe, it fails. My function returns 4 values, but I could not figure out how to use/apply using .withColumn or other method/function using this UDF.

While registering the python function as UDF, I could not understand what data type to be returned. I am sure i messed up somewhere, but dont know where.

Please help

```
import sys
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql as t
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import datetime
import dateutil

def process_data(identifier, eff_date, end_date):
    eff_year = int(eff_date.split("/")[2])
    end_year = int(end_date.split("/")[2])
    
    current_year = eff_year
    while current_year <= end_year:
        
        if str(current_year) in eff_date:
            first_date_in_year = eff_date
        else:
            first_date_in_year = "%02d/%02d/%4d" % (1, 1, current_year)
            
        if str(current_year) in end_date:
            last_date_in_year = end_date
        else:
            last_date_in_year = "%02d/%02d/%4d" % (12, 31, current_year)
            
        print ("|".join([identifier, first_date_in_year, last_date_in_year]))
        current_year += 1

        return identifier, first_date_in_year, last_date_of_year, current_year


def main():
    
    with open('date.input') as f:
        for line in f.read().splitlines():
            identifier, eff_date, end_date = line.split('|')
            process_data(identifier, eff_date, end_date)

process_data_UDF=f.udf(process_data, StringType())

df_explode=df.withColumn("NEWCOLS", process_data_UDF("INDV_ID", "EFF_DATE", "END_DATE"))
df_explode.show()
```

**Input Data**

| Identifier | Eff_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A0001 | 2/1/2019 | 3/31/2021 |
| B0001 | 6/1/2020 | 11/30/2020 |
| C0001 | 6/1/2020 | 1/31/2021 |
| D0001 | 6/1/2020 | 12/31/2021 |
| E0001 | 1/1/2019 | 6/30/2019 |
| E0001 | 1/1/2020 | 12/31/2020 |

**Output Data**

| Identifier | New_Eff_Date | New_End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A0001 | 2/1/2019 | 12/31/2019 |
| A0001 | 01/01/2020 | 12/31/2020 |
| A0001 | 01/01/2021 | 3/31/2021 |
| B0001 | 6/1/2020 | 11/30/2020 |
| C0001 | 6/1/2020 | 12/31/2020 |
| C0001 | 01/01/2021 | 1/31/2021 |
| D0001 | 6/1/2020 | 12/31/2020 |
| D0001 | 01/01/2021 | 12/31/2021 |
| E0001 | 1/1/2019 | 6/30/2019 |
| E0001 | 1/1/2020 | 12/31/2020 |

Comment: you need a function which, from the input `(2/1/2019,3/31/2021)` generate the output : `[(2/1/2019, 12/31/2019), (01/01/2020, 12/31/2020), (01/01/2021, 3/31/2021)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My input dataframe, based on your data :

```py
from datetime import date

b = "Identifier Eff_Date    End_Date".split()

a = [
    ["A0001", date(2019, 2, 1), date(2021, 3, 31)],
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Identifier: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Eff_Date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- End_Date: date (nullable = true)

df.show()
+----------+----------+----------+                                              
|Identifier|  Eff_Date|  End_Date|
+----------+----------+----------+
|     A0001|2019-02-01|2021-03-31|
+----------+----------+----------+
```

---

Here is the function you need :

```py
def generate_dates(start, end):
    out = []
    for i in range((end.year - start.year)+1):
        s = date(start.year+i, 1,1)
        e = date(start.year+i, 12,31)
        out.append((max(s, start), min(e, end)))
    return out
```

let's just transform that in UDF, use it in dataframe with `explode` and you should have your expected result :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T


schema = T.ArrayType(
    T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("New_Eff_Date", T.DateType()),
            T.StructField("New_End_Date", T.DateType()),
        ]
    )
)

generate_dates_udf = F.udf(generate_dates, schema)


df.withColumn(
    "new_dates", generate_dates_udf(F.col("Eff_Date"), F.col("End_Date"))
).withColumn("new_date", F.explode("new_dates")).select(
    "Identifier",
    "new_date.New_Eff_Date",
    "new_date.New_End_Date",
).show()
+----------+------------+------------+
|Identifier|New_Eff_Date|New_End_Date|
+----------+------------+------------+
|     A0001|  2019-02-01|  2019-12-31|
|     A0001|  2020-01-01|  2020-12-31|
|     A0001|  2021-01-01|  2021-03-31|
+----------+------------+------------+
```

---

Same version but full spark :

```py
df = (
    df.withColumn("year", F.explode(F.sequence(F.year("Eff_Date"), F.year("End_Date"))))
    .withColumn(
        "s",
        F.concat_ws("-", F.col("year").cast("string"), F.lit("01"), F.lit("01")).cast(
            "date"
        ),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "e",
        F.concat_ws("-", F.col("year").cast("string"), F.lit("12"), F.lit("31")).cast(
            "date"
        ),
    )
    .select(
        "Identifier",
        F.greatest(F.col("Eff_Date"), F.col("s")).alias("New_Eff_Date"),
        F.least(F.col("End_Date"), F.col("e")).alias("New_End_Date"),
    )
)

df.show()
+----------+------------+------------+                                          
|Identifier|New_Eff_Date|New_End_Date|
+----------+------------+------------+
|     A0001|  2019-02-01|  2019-12-31|
|     A0001|  2020-01-01|  2020-12-31|
|     A0001|  2021-01-01|  2021-03-31|
+----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi Steven, It worked after a few tweaks. But what I noticed was that the processing was very slow. I have a df with about a million rows and it took over an hour. Is this expected??

Comment: UDF is a row by row process. You asked for an UDF ... maybe there is a proper way to do it in pure spark...

Comment: @BhavaniKumarMetla I edited my answer with a full spark solution which reproduce the exact same logic as the UDF.

Comment: Hey Steve, i will try this out as well.

Comment: Hey Steven, The full spark method ended in TypeError: Column is not iterable. I think the two date columns have to be declared as Array before explode can be applied.

Comment: @BhavaniKumarMetla if you execute my code with the first block (data creation) and the last block (spark process), it works without error. If you have this error, you probably changed something in the code. Please check exactly which step fails or add the input data you use. `sequence` is an array so I can use explode on it.